# Universal-Image-Loader: OutOfMemory Error

Tags: universal-image-loader

I am using universal-image-loader-1.6.2.jar (Latest one).
I am trying to Download and cache that images using this library. I have 47 images to be downloaded from server, total of 5.22 Mb.My Maximum images are of dimension are 720X480 and size around 143kb. It goes well till 40-41 images after that it gives error

```
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033): null
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageDecoder.decode(ImageDecoder.java:83)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.saveImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:218)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:138)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:72)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-02 16:30:12.150: E/ImageLoader(31033):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-02 16:30:47.170: E/Adreno200-ES20(31033): <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1318>: **** 31033: glUseProgram(3)
11-02 16:30:47.170: E/Adreno200-ES20(31033): <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1318>: **** 31033: glUseProgram(6)
```

I have seen and implemented suggestion about OOM on git-hub. I followed them still i am getting error.
Here is my code

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"neongall");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .threadPoolSize(3)
    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .offOutOfMemoryHandling()
    .discCacheExtraOptions(720, 480, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)
    .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
    .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
    .imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(120 * 1000, 120 * 1000)) // connectTimeout (5 s), readTimeout (20 s)
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
    .enableLogging()
    .build();
    //Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once on Application start.
    imageLoader.init(config);


    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10))
    .build();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all your configuration:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
.threadPoolSize(3) // equal to default value
.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // equal to default value
.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
.offOutOfMemoryHandling()
.discCacheExtraOptions(720, 480, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)
.discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
.discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // equal to default value
.imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(120 * 1000, 120 * 1000)) // connectTimeout (5 s), readTimeout (20 s)
.defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // equal to default value
.enableLogging()
.build();
```

is equal to

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
.offOutOfMemoryHandling()
.discCacheExtraOptions(720, 480, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)
.discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
.imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(120 * 1000, 120 * 1000))
.enableLogging()
.build();
```

**DON'T COPY CONFIGURATION FROM README!**

Why did you off OutOfMemory handling? If you do this then you should process OOM errors yourself in `ImageLoadingListener.onLoadingFailed(FailReason.OUT_OF_MEMORY)`.

My suggestions for you:

- delete `.offOutOfMemoryHandling()` options in configuration
- delete `.discCacheExtraOptions(720, 480, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)` options in configuration
- use `.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)` in display options
- do you really need RoundedBitmapDisplayer? See docs for it, it creates additional bitmap in memory during rounding. Avoid using it if you can.